# How to restrict Marketing Users to view only Marketing Lead and Accounts and Opp converted from those leads?

Tags: profile, permissions, access

I have Profile called as Marketing Profile. On Lead object, I have made a custom field as Record type. For Marketing users the lead created will be of record type Marketing.
I want Marketing Users to view only Marketing Lead and Accounts and Opp converted from those leads. How to achieve this?
Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set OWD of Lead object as Private. Same is the case with Account object. You might have to check if this fits with rest of your data security settings.
2. Create criteria based sharing rule on lead & account objects, based on recordtype, so that those type of records are visible to the required set of users